# underscore groupby return array instead of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js

I'm trying to create an array of entities grouped by location using underscore.

I have an array of pairs, which looks like this currently `{ location: Location, data: T}[]` I would like to transform it to group by the location look like this `{ location: Location, data: T[]}>[]`

My first instinct was to use `_.GroupBy`

```
const entitiesMap = entities.map(e => ({ location: this.options.locationResolver(e), data: e}));
this.locationEntitiesMap = _.groupBy(entitiesMap, entityPair => entityPair.location);
```

However when I do this this returns an object with the location as the Key.
How can I return a grouped array instead?

Comment: _groupBy is in collections, if you have read the [documentation](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) as it clearly says groups by property , it will always give back the object as it always generates it as a key value pair, you will have to write a custom function instead I suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a reduce

```js
const places = [
  { location: {id: 'USA'},  data:{ eventName:'tech week' }},
  { location: {id: 'GER'},  data:{ eventName:'cheese wheeling' }},
  { location: {id: 'USA'},  data:{ eventName:'mecha fights' }},
  { location: {id: 'AUS'},  data:{ eventName:'kangaroo fight' }}
];

const group = (array, prop) => array.reduce((g, item) => {
    const propVal = item[prop];
    const identifier = propVal.id;
    const entry = g[identifier];
    const data = item.data;

    if (entry) {
      entry.data.push(data);
    } else {
      g[identifier] = {location: propVal, data: [data]};
    }
    return g;
  }, {});

const groups = group(places, 'location');
console.log(group(Object.keys(groups).map((key) => groups[key]), 'location'));
```

Comment: Awesome, this is really a lot more solid than what I was attempt thanks

Comment: This doesn't work location is a Location and not a string

Comment: I fixed it so it matches the question